# ng-model on textarea doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm having an issue using ng-model. When I look at the object, all the properties empty:

```
$scope.edit = {
            name: " ",
            gender: " ",
            major: " ",
            gpa: " ",
            act: " ",
            sat: " ",
            toefl: " ",
            primary: " ",
            secondary: " ",
            country: " ",
            summary: " ",
            past: " ",
            media: " "
        };
```

But when I click submit button all it returns are

[image]
In the html page

Code: https://plnkr.co/edit/HJlfFVjq0cZWJDCDXSXw?p=preview

Comment: Is the code given at the plunker link correct one? pls verify the script.js present there.

Comment: @MateenMomin now it is!

Answer (score 2):

From the plunker (although I couldn't run your code) what is quite obvious is that you are using the same controller `PlayerController` on two different occasions within your form.

> What happens here is that the method `updateUser()` of the `ng-click` attribute is bound to a ***new instance*** of the controller `PlayerController`. Therefore creating a new `scope`, and totally unaware of what changes have been brought to its neighboring namesake controller's scope properties (in this case `edit`).

```
<div ng-controller="PlayerController">
   <!-- ISOLATE region -->
   <textarea ng-model="edit.someproperty"></textarea>
</div>
<div ng-controller="PlayerController">
   <!-- Another isolate region unaware of the above -->
   <button ng-click="updateUser(edit)">Update</button>
</div>
```

### Solution

Wrap the whole form of yours within one single `ngController` directive so that everything within that scope (`ngModel` directives and the method `updateUser`) use the same scope properties.

[**Simple Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/baktash93/mxe4g6pj/1/)

***Note:*** I've also noticed that you've wrapped the `ngController`s within a `form` which is incorrect. A `form` in AngularJS imposes a `FormController` controller object and that controller becomes the immediate parent of your controllers. In fact, the controller that you are creating with `ngController` is meant to handle the logic for your form and not other way round.